# SAP HANA Vora: Failed to start SparkController

Tags: apache-spark, vora

Recently I started to work on SAP HANA Vora 1.0 on AWS. I configured hanaes-site.xml file to read Vora tables, but when trying to start the Controller with ./hanaes start command I receive this error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/spark-sap-datasources-1.0.0-assembly.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

16/04/21 10:29:31 INFO HanaESConfig: Loaded HANA Extended Store Configuration
Spark assembly is not available in class path. Creating Custom class loader from HDFS
Binding with hive-site.xml foind at /usr/sap/spark/controller/conf

16/04/21 10:29:34 INFO Server: Starting Spark Controller

16/04/21 10:29:34 INFO HanaESConfig: Loaded HANA Extended Store Configuration

16/04/21 10:29:51 ERROR LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded(1461234591659,BlockManagerId(2, master.cluster, 41198),1111511531)
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Spark assembly is not available in class path"

You should put the spark assembly file at /usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/external, and make sure hanaes.xml has property:

```
<property>
 <name>sap.hana.es.spark.yarn.jar</name>
 <value>file:///usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/external/spark-assembly-<spark version>-hadoop<hadoop version>.jar</value>
 <final>true</final>
</property>
```

If you already have Spark installed on your cluster, you can find the spark assembly file at $SPARK_HOME/lib.
If you don’t have Spark installed on your cluster, you can download it from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

Thanks

============ Update =================

In hanaes-site.xml, "sap.hana.es.lib.location" should point to "hdfs:///sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/".

It should looks like below:

```
<property>
 <name>sap.hana.es.spark.yarn.jar</name>
 <value>file:///usr/sap/spark/controller/lib/external/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar</value>
 <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
 <name>sap.hana.es.server.port</name>
 <value>7860</value>
 <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
 <name>sap.hana.es.lib.location</name>
 <value>hdfs:///sap/hana/spark/libs/thirdparty/</value>
 <final>true</final>
</property>
```

In addition, I would also suggest you to use [Vora 1.2 AWS developer edition](https://go.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-voratrdm/index.html)